# $cond inside $sum

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I want to make a compound query in mongodb, which must add 1 for each true that it detects, but it is not working correctly, since it counts both the true and the false.

```
{ 
  _id: "resumen",
  summary: { $sum:
               { $cond: [ asistencia: false, 1, 0 ] }
  }
}
```

Example of my data:

```
   {
       _id: ObjectId(5fb8722ec775d2f89c47b00d),
       id_asesor: ObjectId(5fb72a4245494b99847d63c2),
       nombre_evento:" Reunión"persona:"Joaquin Vazquez Muños",
       inicio: 2020-11-20T06:00:00.000+00:00,
       fin_ev: 2020-11-20T07:00:00.000+00:00,
       duracion: 60,
       asistencia: false             <- this is the data to validate
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `{ $cond: [ {$eq:["$asistencia", false]}, 1, 0 ] }`. `$cond` is getting 3 parameters where first is the condition. So used `$eq` to check the condition